# Methods for debugging package conflicts

Tags: errors, packages, incompatibility, debugging, elsarticle

... that don't make me want to pull my (remaining) hair out.

I'm preparing a long journal article with a wide array of necessary packages and a publisher-specific class file.

In this specific case, I've recently added

```
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
```

When building the TeX file I'm now encountering a typical conflict error:

```
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\algorithms\algorithm.sty"
 Package: algorithm 2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environment


! LaTeX Error: Command \c@algorithm already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.96 \floatname
               {algorithm}{\ALG@name}
Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.
```

The resulting PDF looks fine, including the new algorithms, but since I'm collaborating on the source with other parties—and since I'm the kind of person who has nightmares about unbalanced parentheses—I don't want to commit changes that introduce error messages.

Aside from this specific case (which I assume is quite specialised, but which serves as a useful example), I'm wondering if there's any methods or helpful tips to debug conflicts like this? I have tried commenting out various packages to do a "binary search" on the problematic package, but then I encounter other errors or the build fails due to the necessary packages being omitted. I have tried building up the packages from an MWE but it is time consuming given the complexity of the document and not (yet) yielding any insights.

This leads me to wonder if there's a better way ... how would a TeX expert approach the problem?

For example, are there any hints to be had from the pdfTex .log file as to where `\c@algorithm` is already defined? Is there another method to trace where the definition is? Maybe the definition can be renamed before including the `algorithm` package? Maybe there's an online resource that offers a matrix of typical package conflicts? Or maybe there's some other general method to identify and resolve such conflicts?

(Of course, there's a bunch of [incompatibility questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incompatibility) already on this site, but I could not find any that address generic methods on how to *identify* conflicts/incompatibilities.)

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to the comments below and David's help, I was able to fix the specific case, which relates to both the `elsart` class file I'm using and the `algorithm` package I've included defining a counter for algorithms. The method to identify this conflict was to go through the log file as David suggested to find where the `\c@algorithm` counter was registered. To resolve the problem, I added `\makeatletter\let\c@algorithm\relax\makeatother` before including the `algorithm` package.

The question remains open as to generic methods (such as looking through the nested file inclusions in the log file) for identifying and resolving conflicts.

Comment: Cheers David, I had tried that. If I comment out the import of `algorithm` in the article, it indeed removes the error, but I lose the horizontal-lined framing of the algorithms. But weirdly, if I set up an MWE to test this, I can keep both the `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` packages without a problem. Hence it seems there's somehow a "third party" involved.

Comment: `\c@algorithm ` is the latex counter `algorithm`  so you have declared the counter twice.  although I get no clash if I load those two, and your error is on loading algorithm, ie before algpseudocode is loaded so you must have another algorithm??? package loaded?

Comment: The log should show a line when the c@algorithm register is allocated and looking up to the preceding `(` will tell you which file that is in

Comment: The log notes `\c@algorithm=\count87` ... I had noticed this before but since it was in a long list of such declarations, I didn't pay heed. However, the package mentioned before that is `latexsym`. If I comment out `latexsym` the error remains (and so does the counter register for `c@algorithm`, so presumably something else includes `latexsym`). Now I just need to find where `latexsym` is coming from. And this is precisely the type of debugging tips I was hoping for in the question, thanks!

Comment: no latexsym doesn't declare that, I suspect that the `)` marking the close of latexsym.sty is before that line, you need to match `()` pairs as they mark file open/close

Comment: Right. It's in an auxiliary publisher-specific class file (`elsart.cls` for Elsevier) called from the document class file (`elsart3p.cls`). The former file defines an algorithm environment that looks ugly. Removing those declarations from the class file removes the problem. I wonder is there a way in the main document file to drop that counter without changing the standard class files?

Comment: you can probably just `\makeatletter\let\c@algorithm\relax\makeatother` before loading your algorithm package, then it'll get re-allocated which wastes one register but...

Comment: Perfect, that resolves this specific case, thanks David!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can locate where the register `\c@algorithm` is being defined by looking in the log file for a line

```
\c@algorithm=\count??
```

Then working out which package file was being read at that time by working backwards up the log file matching `(` and `)` which mark the open and close of files by TeX's file reading system. The full path to each opened file is shown after the `(` and a `)` is printed to the log when the end of file has been reached.